# How to extend NHibernate to support more databases?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

If I needed to get NHibernate to support more databases (not included in the list of supported: https://www.hibernate.org/361.html), assuming that database can be accessed using it's built-in query language,but not SQL (example: http://kx.com/Products/kdb+.php)...

- How will I be able to get NHibernate to work with these databases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NHibernate is designed to operate with dialects of SQL and not *ad hoc* query languages. This will be very tricky to accomplish. But to answer your question, you need:

1. An ADO.NET provider for your database (this would be a separate question).
2. A Driver class (derived from NHibernate's DriverBase). Here is one I have written in the past (somewhat anonymised):

   ```
   public sealed class XxxClientDriver : DriverBase
   {
       public override IDbConnection CreateConnection()
       {
           return XxxClientFactory.Instance.CreateConnection();
       }
       public override IDbCommand CreateCommand()
       {
           return XxxClientFactory.Instance.CreateCommand();
       }
       public override bool UseNamedPrefixInSql
       {
           get { return true; }
       }
       public override bool UseNamedPrefixInParameter
       {
           get { return true; }
       }
       public override string NamedPrefix
       {
           get { return "@"; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Possibly (definitely in your case) a Dialect, deriving from NHibernate's Dialect class, that defines classes to render each particular syntax element in your language (note, though, that this is still SQL-orientated, which is I suspect where you are going to fall down here). An example in my case:

   ```
   public sealed class XxxDialect : Dialect
   {
       public override JoinFragment CreateOuterJoinFragment()
       {
           return new XxxJoinFragment();
       }
   }
   ```
4. As many non-standard syntax elements (compared to normal SQL) as your language has. Again, an example from my case:

   ```
   public sealed class XxxJoinFragment : JoinFragment
   {
       private readonly SqlStringBuilder _afterFrom;
       public XxxJoinFragment()
       {
           _afterFrom = new SqlStringBuilder();
       }
       private SqlStringBuilder AfterFrom
       {
           get { return _afterFrom; }
       }
       public override SqlString ToFromFragmentString
       {
           get { return _afterFrom.ToSqlString(); }
       }
       public override SqlString ToWhereFragmentString
       {
           get { return SqlString.Empty; }
       }
       public override void AddJoin(string tableName, string alias,
           string[] fkColumns, string[] pkColumns,
           JoinType joinType)
       {
           AddCrossJoin(tableName, alias);
       }
       public override void AddJoin(string tableName, string alias,
           string[] fkColumns, string[] pkColumns,
           JoinType joinType, string on)
       {
           AddJoin(tableName, alias, fkColumns, pkColumns, joinType);
       }
       public override void AddCrossJoin(string tableName, string alias)
       {
           AfterFrom.Add(", ").Add(tableName).Add(" ").Add(alias);
       }
       public override void AddJoins(SqlString fromFragment, SqlString whereFragment)
       {
           AddFromFragmentString(fromFragment);
       }
       public override bool AddCondition(string condition)
       {
           return true;
       }
       public override bool AddCondition(SqlString condition)
       {
           return true;
       }
       public override void AddFromFragmentString(SqlString fromFragmentString)
       {
           AfterFrom.Add(fromFragmentString);
       }
   }
   ```

As you can see, in my case (a SQL-based query language with implicit join conditions) this was not too hard. But in your case I suspect you're going to be up against it. Good luck!